# How can I only group on PDF output (and not Excel output) in BIRT report?

Tags: pdf, report, grouping, birt, xls

In reports that use Table Groups and rows with aggregations based on those groups, I set each group row to Hide Element for xls file output. However, that just hides the aggregate values, and the data is still being grouped. How can I make it so that there is no grouping logic for the Excel outputs?

Answer (score 2):

Just create two report in one layout one for PDF & another for Excel based upon the export/parameters actions you can just hide and show the report.